# To what is $P (a\times b)$ equal when $P$ is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, orthogonality

Suppose that $P$ is an ortogonal matrix.

Then we have the following:

($a$ and $b$ are vectors)

$$\frac{Pa \times Pb}{\|Pa \times Pb\|}=\frac{\det{(P)}P (a\times b)}{\|\det{(P)}P (a\times b)\|}=\frac{\pm P (a\times b)}{\|\pm P (a\times b)\|}=\frac{\pm P (a\times b)}{\| P (a\times b)\|}=\frac{\pm P (a\times b)}{\|  a\times b\|}$$

Is this correct so far?

How can we continue?

To what is $P (a\times b)$ equal when $P$ is orthogonal?

$$$$

---

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I want to show what happens to the second fundamental form of a surface $\sigma$ if we apply an isometry.

An isometry is $\tilde{\sigma}=P\sigma+a$.

Then $$\tilde{\sigma}_u=P\sigma_u , \ \tilde{\sigma}_v=P\sigma_v, \ \tilde{\sigma}_{uu}=P\sigma_{uu}, \ \tilde{\sigma}_{uv}=P\sigma_{uv}, \ \tilde{\sigma}_{vv}=P\sigma_{vv}$$

We have $$\tilde{\textbf{N}}=\frac{\tilde{\sigma}_u\times\tilde{\sigma}_v}{\|\tilde{\sigma}_u\times\tilde{\sigma}_v\|}=\frac{P\sigma_u \times P\sigma_v}{\|P\sigma_u \times P\sigma_v\|}=\frac{\pm P (\sigma_u\times \sigma_v)}{\|  \sigma_u \times \sigma_v\|}$$

Can we eliminate $P$ ?

Comment: So can we not continue from the point I left it? @Batman

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is a special orthogonal matrix($det(P)=1$) then $P(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})=P(\mathbf{a})\times P(\mathbf{b})$. A matrix of this kind is a rotation. Note that a orthogonal matrix preserve the scalar product!

Comment: The initial expression was of the form $P(a)\times P(b)$ then I changed it into $\pm P(a\times b)$. Can we maybe get rid of $P$ at the expression $\frac{\pm P (a\times b)}{\|  a\times b\|}$ ?

Comment: The norm of axb is equal to the norm of P(a)xP(b) , then P(a)xP(b)=\pm P(axb). In particular if det(P)=1 ,holds  the assertion in my answer.